# Arduino BLE multiple definition

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to read out data from a temperature sensor, connected to my Arduino Blend Micro (http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/) and send this value via bluetooth beacons to an android smartphone. Both tasks are able to run successful, when they are in a seperated sketch. But when I put them together in one sketch (also put the libraries together), several errors appears. The given error tells me, that there are some multiple definitions in my libraries.

> libraries\BLEPeripheral\utility\aci_queue.cpp.o: In function
>   `aci_queue_init(aci_queue_t*)':
>
> C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\BLEPeripheral\utility/aci_queue.cpp:33:
>   multiple definition of `aci_queue_init(aci_queue_t*)'
>
> libraries\BLE_SDK_for_Arduino\aci_queue.cpp.o:C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\BLE_SDK_for_Arduino\src/aci_queue.cpp:31:
>   first defined here
>
> libraries\BLEPeripheral\utility\aci_queue.cpp.o: In function
>   `aci_queue_init(aci_queue_t*)':
>
> C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\BLEPeripheral\utility/aci_queue.cpp:33:
>   multiple definition of `aci_queue_dequeue(aci_queue_t*,
>   hal_aci_data_t*)'
>
> libraries\BLE_SDK_for_Arduino\aci_queue.cpp.o:aci_queue.cpp:(.text._Z17aci_queue_dequeueP11aci_queue_tP14hal_aci_data_t+0x0):
>   first defined here

The problem seems to be between the libraries BLEPeripheral and BLE_SDK_for_Arduino. But the research in the internet tells me, that they should be compatible.

Here is my code:

```
    //"RBL_nRF8001.h/spi.h/boards.h" is needed in every new project enter code here
    #include <boards.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <Adafruit_BME280.h>
    #include <RBL_nRF8001.h>
    #include <RBL_services.h>
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <EddystoneBeacon.h>

    Adafruit_BME280 bme;

    #define EDDYSTONE_BEACON_REQ   6
    #define EDDYSTONE_BEACON_RDY   7
    #define EDDYSTONE_BEACON_RST   4

    EddystoneBeacon eddystoneBeacon = EddystoneBeacon(EDDYSTONE_BEACON_REQ, EDDYSTONE_BEACON_RDY, EDDYSTONE_BEACON_RST);

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      delay(500);
      bme.begin();
      eddystoneBeacon.setLocalName("RoomSupervisor");
    }

    void loop() {
        Serial.write("Start");
        while(1){
          Serial.write("Try to send...  ");
          eddystoneBeacon.begin(-18, "WHAT THE HELL DOESN'T WORK!?");
          eddystoneBeacon.loop();
          Serial.write("   succesful! \n");
          delay(3000);
        }
    }
```

I really need both libraries to work with bluetooth and my sensor. But how can I do this, when there are multiple definitions? I already tried to delete parts of one library, to get rid of the errors, but then my sketch didn't work properly anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just the RedBearLabs library. Dont delete parts of the library. Get rid of the sdk in the librarys folder and copy just the necessary librarys that you want (need) to include in your Arduino library folder.